# How to resolve Hard disk failure with new external SSD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd, external-hard-drive

[BIOS Boot Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqopG.jpg)

I have an error message on startup (SMART Hard Disk Error has detected an imminent failure, run the Hard Disk test in systems diagnostics). I can't even get to the login screen. I have plugged up a new external ssd (via usb to sata) as I am trying to run my laptop on it instead of the hard drive to fix this. I booted it in BIOS mode and tried changing the boot order (attached image) but am still getting the failure message, and when I try to continue it just shows a dim, blue screen indefinitely.

I feel like I'm missing a step or something, as I've never put together a computer or anything before. My next course of action is to take apart my laptop (HP Notebook) and try to unplug the hard drive, as I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: " take apart my laptop (HP Notebook) and try to unplug the hard drive" Yes, the SSD has failed an needs replaced.

Comment: @Moab thats what I want to avoid to do due to the complexity of taking apart my laptop. I was seeing if there was an option to disable the hard drive disk from BIOS or System Diagnostics menu. But I appreicate your very insightful input.